# TextView scrolling does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-scrollview, pinchzoom

This a pinch to zoom app with a `TextView`. I want to zoom the `TextView` contents.

```
public class sukharta extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView scaleGesture;
    ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sukharta);
        scaleGesture = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        scaleGesture.setText(R.string.sukharta);
        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, (ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener) new simpleOnScaleGestureListener());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sukharta, (ViewGroup) menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float size = scaleGesture.getTextSize();
            Log.d("TextSizeStart", String.valueOf(size));

            float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            Log.d("Factor", String.valueOf(factor));


            float product = size*factor;
            Log.d("TextSize", String.valueOf(product));
            scaleGesture.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);

            size = scaleGesture.getTextSize();
            Log.d("TextSizeEnd", String.valueOf(size));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**`sukharta.xml` file**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The zoom works for the `TextView` without the `ScrollView` but the content goes out of frame and I cant scroll down to view that.
But when I add `ScrollView`, I cant zoom. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this set your scrollview  property `android:fillViewport="true"`

```
<ScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true">

 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If I use this I cant zoom the textview.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLines="LINES"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: doesnt help me. the activity just crashes

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.androidsrc.videosplash/net.androidsrc.videosplash.sukharta}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)' on a null object reference

Comment: It seems you haven't initialized your textview

Comment: I have initialized the textview. Kindly check the code on top.

Comment: activity loads fine now. But problem with zooming. Can't zoom

Comment: If I dont use                                               textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());                      I can use the zoom.

Comment: I tried adding more content to the textview. scrolling works fine but the problem is with zooming now. Zoom doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

may be NestedScrollView work for you try above code..

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: activity crashes

Comment: Still the same. The activity loads fine but I cant zoom.

Comment: I tried adding more content to the textview. It all works fine but the problem is with zooming now. Zoom doesnt work

Comment: try to resolve using debugger that code calls onTouchEvent works or not...